# FTDI TTL with Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, driver

in order to send commands to an external device, I use a wire called TTL-232R-3V3 of FTDI. I want to set there specific pathways to high or to low. Parity or stop bits are not needed.

My operating system is Ubuntu Linux 13.04.

I want to develop an Java or C application, which can send these commands. But there is an error when I try to install the driver for the wire:

I'm following [this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux%20.pdf) instruction, and I decided to install the D2XX driver. I think I've successfully installed the Shared Object and Static Library as described in step 2.1, anyway I didn't got any error messages.

But when I try to compile sample code, as described in step 3, I got the following output executing the `make -B` command.

```
for n in BitMode EEPROM/erase EEPROM/read EEPROM/write EEPROM/user/read EEPROM/user/size EEPROM/user/write Events LargeRead MultiThread SetVIDPID Simple Timeouts ; do make -C $n || exit 1; done
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/BitMode'
gcc main.c -o bitmode -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib  
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/BitMode'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/erase'
gcc main.c -o erase -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/erase'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/read'
gcc main.c -o read -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/read'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/write'
gcc main.c -o write -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/write'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/user/read'
gcc main.c -o readua -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/user/read'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/user/size'
gcc main.c -o sizeua -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/user/size'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/user/write'
gcc main.c -o writeua -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/EEPROM/user/write'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/Events'
gcc main.c -o events -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/Events'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/LargeRead'
gcc main.c -o largeread -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/LargeRead'
make[1]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/MultiThread'
gcc main.c -o multi -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples/MultiThread'
gcc main.c -o multi -Wall -Wextra -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoAsrRg.o: undefined reference to symbol     'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-    gnu/libpthread.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: could not read symbols: Ungültiger Vorgang
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make[1]: *** [multi] Fehler 1
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/home/robin/Dokumente/Java/Stepper/lib/release/examples    /MultiThread'
make: *** [subdirs] Fehler 1
```

How can I fix that error? Has someone experiences with this wire and Linux?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the sample, or one of its dependencies, is using pthreads, but the Makefile isn't configured for that.

Edit the Makefile and add `-pthread` to `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.  You can probably do that by adding the lines

```
CFLAGS += -pthread
LDFLAGS += -pthread
```

However, you may not need the D2XX library at all.  The FTDI kernel driver should create a `/dev/ttyUSB`*n* device that you can use just like a "real" serial port.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for the late answer. Yes, you're right there is a device called `ttyUSB0`. I've tried to open the serial port as described in [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming:Unix/termios#open.282.29) tutorial. I downloaded the termios header file but I can't execute it. What is fd? Is it a variable? Eclipse is just remarking: `Symbol 'fd' could not be resolved`. Do you (or someone else) know a good tutorial?

Comment: fd is the usual variable name for a file descriptor.  As in `int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_EXCL);`  Ok yeah, that tutorial has most of the important pieces, you just need to declare fd as `int fd;`  Normally you should have a `termios.h` file already on your Linux system, it's one of the system headers.  If not, you may need to use your package manager to install the system headers.

Comment: Okay. I now have managed (I hope so) to open, to customize and to close the port. [View the Code here](http://ubuntuone.com/2OI7ffdDMjpZWOuZ5xFbrG). But I don't know what command I have to use, to set one pathway to high/low. I have one LED connected to ground and to one other wire, which is on when I connect the "serial port" to my computer. How can I switch it off and on again?

Comment: @IndexOutOfBoundsException: Oh, if you want to control the FTDI CBUS pins in bitbang mode, then yes you do need the D2XX.  You can't just hook LEDs to FTDI pins though.  You need current-limiting resistors, and possibly a transistor to switch larger currents than the GPIOs are capable of.  If you are using the GPIOs, low-side switching usually works better.  Post a schematic and I can probably tell you if you need wiring changes.  But that discussion really should be on EE.stackexchange and not SO.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I already have an resistor. How can use ee.stackexchange? You're right, actually this is awful.

Comment: @IndexOutOfBoundsException: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/  It's a website like this one except for circuits and programming devices.